# docker-compose: declare an alias for a non-docker server name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I defined a container in a docker-compose file. I want to access a non-docker server name (say database.xyz) inside the container as the dns name mydb.

How to define that in the compose file?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `extra_hosts` section:

```
extra_hosts: 
- "somehost:162.242.195.82" 
- "otherhost:50.31.209.229"
```

Documentation on this can be found at: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts

Comment: But I want to alias a name to a name, not a IP to a name.

Comment: I believe that would be a feature request for the docker engine's built in DNS capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases).

Here is the example.

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
    user_network:
        driver: bridge

services:

    listener:
        image: asleea/test
        command: nc -vlkp 10000

        networks:
            user_network:
                aliases:
                    - listener_alias

    client:
        image: asleea/test
        command: nc listener_alias 10000

        depends_on:
            - listener

        networks:
            user_network:
                aliases:
                    - client_alias
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understood me or I understood you, but I want to alias a name that is not a container (say database.xyz) to an alias mydb inside the container(s). Isn't this the other way?

Comment: @Adriano dos Santos Fernandes, You mean alias pointing a host out of `docker network`?

Comment: Without any additional configuration, my container can access database.xyz directly. I just want to give a alias name to it.